# How can I detect what's calling an .exe when pressing a keyboard button? (and hook it)

Tags: windows, debugging, hardware

On my keyboard, there's a button that opens Windows 7 calculator when pressed. How would you capture what's calling/opening it?

Because it's a Logitech keyboard, common sense would say it's via SetPoint software/service, so I would normally start by observing those in Process Monitor. But because I'm doing this as a hands-on reversing exercise rather than merely reprogramming a keyboard button, I'd like to approach it as if I didn't have background knowledge of SetPoint or third-party keyboard software.

Is there a way I could trace/capture the behind-the-scenes activity from keypress to calc.exe opening?

Comment: You would need a USB traffic monitor/capture tool; assuming the keyboard uses a USB interface for communication.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the process creation.

If you'd like more granular detail, use [Rohitab's API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) and monitor on CreateProcess* functions. [Here's an answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1980/161) I gave on this site with regard to monitoring registry reading.